# Can ffmpeg drawtext filter read RTF file as video overlay?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, stream, rtf, drawtext

i'm using ffmpeg with ffserver to read a video stream, add a text overlay and re-stream the video in mpjpeg format. The text overlay is stored in a file, reloaded every frame with the drawtext ffmpeg filter and all is working properly.

Now I want to make more awesome the overlayed infos, I googled something like "ffmpeg drawtext rtf" and "ffmpeg drawtext html" but I dind't found any solution...

Is this possible? 
Can I use any kind of Rich Text format file as an overlay in ffmpeg drawtext filter?

Thanks for reading (and maybe help me).
R.

Answer (score 2):

There's no `RTF`/`HTML` support just plain `UTF-8`

> **textfile**
>
> A text file containing text to be drawn. The text must be a sequence of UTF-8 encoded characters.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext

You can create a transparent `PNG` and overlay it instead:

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will try to create a transparent PNG and report here my results.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option is to make ASS or SRT subtitles and hardsub them with the [subtitles filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles). Aegisub is a good subtitle making tool.